# Chef - Ruby - ArgumentsError expected 0

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, chef-infra

I'm trying to write a cookbook in Chef (very new) and I get the following error I cannot wrap my head around.

```
template node '/etc/selinux/config' do 
    source "config.erb"
    mode "0644"
    variables(
        :selinux_state => node['selinux']['selinux-state'],
        :selinux_type => node['selinux']['selinux-type']
        )
    owner duser
    group dgroup 
    action :create
    ignore_failure true

end
```

> FATAL: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

I checked the documentation and as far as I can tell I am following the correct syntax.

Could anyone please enlighten me where the error is?

Comment: "I checked the documentation and as far as I can tell I am following the correct syntax." – You didn't get a `SyntaxError`, so of course your syntax is correct. If your syntax was incorrect, your code wouldn't even get parsed and you would get a `SyntaxError`. You are getting an `ArgumentError`, which is a *semantic error*, not a syntactical one.

Comment: "Could anyone please enlighten me where the error is?" – The error message tells you that. It includes line and column number as well as the method for which this error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `node` in the resource declaration. Change:

```
template node '/etc/selinux/config' do
```

to

```
template '/etc/selinux/config' do
```